# How can I return a int[N]* in a function in C

Tags: c

With a formal parameter, I can declare a pointer of type `int[N]*` (it is `int (*A)[COL]` in the code below). But I wonder how can I return the function to a pointer of this type?

In my code, `int (*)[COL]` make no sense.

I thank you so much.

```
int (*)[COL] creat_2D_Array(int(*A)[COL], int ROW, int COL) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 20 + 1;
        }
    }
    return A;
}
//I add some code below after discussion with user3386109

//Or how can i return to a pointer of int[10]*
int (*)[10] creat_2D_Array(int(*A)[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 20 + 1;
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason you want to *return* `A`? You modify it in place, so I don't really see any need to return it.

Comment: yes, you right. But I just want to try something. Because I can return a function to a pointer of `int*`, but I don't know how to return to `int[N]*`

Comment: Then the simple answer is: You can't. Not unless `N` (or `COL` from your example) is a global symbol or macro.

Comment: how about if a definite number instead of N or COL.
    int (*)[10] creat_2D_Array(int(*A)[10], int ROW, int COL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 20 + 1;
        }
    }
    return A;
    }

Comment: Well yeah that could work, but only if that's the true type of `A`. It also means you can't call the function with matrices of other dimensions.

Comment: Oh, and unless `ROW` and `COL` are global variables, constants or macros, then define those arguments *first* or your definition of the argument `A` is invalid as well.

Comment: Move the `)[10]` to the end, just before the opening bracket `{`

Comment: `int (*)[10]` in the function still makes no sense in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: `int (*creat_2D_Array(int (*array)[10]))[10] {`

Comment: Oh you could use `typedef` to create an alias and use it as a return type. Still not flexible or accommodating different sizes.

Comment: `int (*creat_2D_Array(int (*array)[10]))[10] {`. I can do it.

But `int (*creat_2D_Array(int (*array)[10], int num1, int num2))[10] {` make no sense in Visual studio 2017

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude typedef is a bad idea. Instead pass an array pointer to VLA by parameter. Then it is completely flexible and can have any size.

Comment: @loveCLoveC Visual Studio 2017 is from the year 1990-something. You'll need to use a less ancient C compiler to use 20 year old features like VLA.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is like for function pointers, but you just use `[...]` instead of `(...)`, like:

```
type (*identifier)[size]
```

Put the function name and parameter list inside `(* ... )`:

```
int (*creat_2D_Array(int (*A)[COL], int ROW, int COL_param))[COL] {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 20 + 1;
        }
    }
    return A;
}

int (*creat_2D_Array_1(int(*A)[10]))[10] {
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
       {
           A[i][j] = rand() % 20 + 1;
       }
   }
   return A;
}
```

The `COL` in the first `creat_2D_Array` function has to be a constant expression.

I sometimes use a `void*` pointer to return a pointer to an array of unknown size from such functions with combinations of simple VLAs declarations inside function parameter list and expect the caller to do the casting:

```
  void *creat_2D_Array(int ROW, int COL, int A[ROW][COL]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 20 + 1;
        }
    }
    return A;
}

int main() {
   int input[5][6];
   int (*output)[6] = creat_2D_Array(5, 6, input);
   // remember these are pointers, you return the same pointer you inputted
   assert(input == output);
}
```

I find such an approach hard to maintain. Writing some access API and functions to some obfuscated object or structure is easier to work with (and allows for assertions and some other checks).

Comment: This doesn't work when the array is a VLA, as it ought to be, since functions with hard-coded integer constants are mildly useful.

Comment: There are no VLAs here, these are pointers to arrays of constant size.

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying that it is a mistake that there are no VLAs here. If you hard code array dimensions, you have a tight coupling between everything and might as well skip the function. Also, I would expect a function called "creat_2D_Array" to create a 2D array...

Answer (score 0):

You can't return arrays in C. And unfortunately, you cannot return a pointer to VLA either.

This is because the function is declared at file scope and you can't have a VLA there, as it would need to have static storage duration. C doesn't allow this:

```
// illegal C, syntax error:
int (*create_2D_array(size_t ROW, size_t COL))[ROW][COL];
```

The solution is to use a pointer to a pointer to an array, then pass that as parameter:

```
void create_2D_array (size_t ROW, size_t COL, int(**arr)[ROW][COL]);
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void create_2D_array (size_t ROW, size_t COL, int(**arr)[ROW][COL])
{
  *arr = malloc( sizeof(int[ROW][COL]) );

  int(*a)[COL] = **arr; // use tmp pointer to allow a[i][j] syntax
  for(size_t i=0; i<ROW; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<COL; j++)
    {
      a[i][j] = i*COL + j;
    }
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  const size_t row = 3;
  const size_t col = 2;

  int(*arr)[row][col];
  create_2D_array(row, col, &arr);

  int(*a)[col] = *arr;
  for(size_t i=0; i<row; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<col; j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  free(arr);
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: The statement “you cannot return a pointer to VLA either” is false. A function may return a pointer to a variable length array that is created via `malloc` (as in `int (*f(int n))[] { int (*p)[n] = malloc(sizeof *p); …; return p; }`) or that is made known to it through a parameter or other means.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The example labelled "illegal C, syntax error" shows how you cannot return a pointer to VLA. Return meaning using the `return` statement. The working example further down shows how to do it properly. Perhaps you could try to read the answer before down-voting?

Comment: That example shows you cannot declare a function to return a pointer to a variable length array. It does not show you cannot return a pointer to a variable length array, from a function declared to return a pointer to an array of unknown length.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So? You cannot write a function that returns a pointer to an array of unknown length either. Not without using `void*` or other ugly patches.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's as bad as returning a pointer to void though, there's no type safety. It is not a pointer to a VLA but a pointer to an array of incomplete type.

Comment: First, the statement “you cannot return a pointer to VLA either” is false. Second, your comment about reading the question was rude—and is a standard you failed to live up to by failing to “read” my comment, which contained a disproof of your false statement. Third, there is type safety: The returned object is correctly typed as an array of elements of a complete type. The only missing information is the size of the array, which is also missing whenever any array is passed by a pointer to its first element.